# Which method handles the changing appearance of a Fragment UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

Basically, I have a list of detail fragments and each one represents a list of peers of that phone. When one of these DeviceDetails is tapped on, a selection of buttons and text appears. Which of these buttons and text appears depends on the status of the phone; it is either connected to the phone being used, or it is available for connection.

I currently use the fragment's onCreateView to make 3 buttons appear. 1 of these buttons should appear every time, and the other 2 alternate depending on the connected/available state.

I am trying to figure out which overridden fragment method should handle the changing UI's. It should just be a case of if statements (or maybe switch statements?) but I am not sure where to place these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if let's say you have an Activity  and it is hosting all these Fragments.

I assume there is some event that triggers this state to happen, maybe in that Activity

```
public void onSomeEventThatICareAbout(EventDetails deets) {
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_with_buttons);
    if (fragment != null) {
         ((MyButtonsFragment)).disableButtons(deets);
    }
}
```

Basically just treat the fragment like any other component and call methods on it based on events like normal, whether it is an onClick(), a AsyncTask callback, or whatever. Just call the function right on the fragment.

Define your own way for your fragment to do what you want,

```
public void disableButtons(EventDetails deets) {
    View view = getView();
    view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnabled(false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button2).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Man, still having a tough time getting my head around it. Am I right in thinking that only one Detail Fragment is created and I'd have to change it depending on which one was selected from the List Fragment?

Comment: Solved it. Thank you. All it took was some switch statements in my DetailFragment's showDetails method, based on the device.status.